# relative import with `__package__` specified

Tags: python, import

I know there are hundreds of post on this issue, but as fare as I see, mine is a bit different.
My project structure is the following:

```
package/
    >script.py
    >__init__.py
    >submodule
        >__init__.py
        >otherstuff.py
        >...
```

You should be able to run `script.py` simpy as a script `$ ./package/script.py`.
`script.py` needs information of `submodule.__init__` so i attempt do do a relative import of `submodule`.
According to [PEP-366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) it is not possible to do relative imports, because if the script is run, `__name__` will be set to `'__main__'` and `__package__` to `None`.

To still use relative imports I manually set `__package__ = 'package'` before my imports. This allows me to properly do `import package`.
However `from . import plotter` yields

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script.py", line 9, in <module>
    import package
  File ".../package/script.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import submodule
ImportError: cannot import name submodule
```

if I previously imported `package`.
Else it yields

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import submodule
SystemError: Parent module 'package' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Can anyone help me how to fix the relative imports?

---

I don't want to use path hacks like

```
from os import path, pardir                                                                                                                                  
from sys import path as syspath
PATH = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))                                                                                                                  
syspath.append(path.join(PATH, pardir))
```

and it is also not possible to add `package` to the path.